# Check whether numpy array row is smaller than the next

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Suppose i have the following array:

```
In [1]: k
Out[1]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [7],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6]])
```

I would like to check whether each row of k is smaller than the next.

I tried the following but it did not work:

```
In [2]: k[:,0]<k[:+1,0]
Out[2]: array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `np.diff` along axis 0 and check whether the result is greater than 0.

```
arr = np.array([[0],
                [1],
                [2],
                [7],
                [4],
                [5],
                [6]])
np.diff(arr, axis=0) > 0

array([[ True],  1 > 0
       [ True],  2 > 1
       [ True],  7 > 2
       [False],  4 > 7
       [ True],  5 > 4
       [ True]]) 6 > 5
```

There is no row follow `[6]` and thus the result is one row shorter.

Comment: Thank you. Is this equivalent to `k[-1,0] < k[0:, 0]`?

Comment: You can read about [`diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) @user177324 Your formulation seems not match your title.

Comment: I understand the logic but `k[-1,0] < k[0:, 0]` produces all rows? Your approach if i understand it correctly assumes that the last row is always false?

Comment: My method would not produce a result for the last row. If you want to define the result of the last row as false, you can add it later.  `k[-1,0]` only selects one element.

Answer (score 1):

The `k[:+1,0]` means `"from 0 to +1"`, there is only one element. You need:

```
k[:-1, 0] < k[1:, 0]
```