# Check if two numpy array rows simultaneously satisfy a proposition

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

This is a follow-up post to a previous question of mine:

[Check whether numpy array row is smaller than the next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978144/check-whether-numpy-array-row-is-smaller-than-the-next)

Suppose i have the following numpy array:

```
a=np.reshape(np.array([[79,np.nan,87,77,92,133,99,121,103,118,126, 
133,131,67]]),(7,2))

In [1]: a
Out[1]: 
array([[  79.,   nan],
       [  87.,   77.],
       [  92.,  133.],
       [  99.,  121.],
       [ 103.,  118.],
       [ 126.,  133.],
       [ 131.,  67.]])
```

I would like to create a new column or array which will be a True/False indicator testing the following proposition:

```
a[-1, 0] < a[1:, 0] and a[-1, 1] > a[1:, 1]
```

The result that i expect is the following:

```
False (because the first value of column 1 is nan)
False
True
True
False
True
False
```

I have tried different variations of the solutions described in my previous post, but so far i have been unsuccessful.

EDIT:

The idea is to test whether 87<92 and at the same time 77>133 which is False. Then 92<99 and 133>121 which is True etc.

Comment: Your result will be a vector 6 times `False` because 131 (`a[-1,0]`) is `>` every other value in that column. Same for col 2. Can you please explain your proposition more exactly?

Comment: I just did, thank you. Hopefully this is more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will use exactly the same strategy than [Tai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48978474/3104974) in your previous post:

```
b = np.diff(a, axis=0)

[[   8.   nan]
 [   5.   56.]
 [   7.  -12.]
 [   4.   -3.]
 [  23.   15.]
 [   5.  -66.]]
```

And now you use a the logic function [`np.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) on array `b`. Since you always want a *trailing False*, we can just append it:

```
result = np.logical_and(b[:,0] > 0, b[:,1] < 0)
result = np.append(result, np.array([False]))

[False False  True  True False True False]
```

(edited my post according to your comments)

**Note**: Comparing values with `nan` will always return `False`. So if `nan` appears in some row in the middle, it will always yield *two* rows that evaluate to `False`.

Comment: Just to break it down: The first `False = 79 < 87 and nan > 76`, second `False = 87 < 92 and 77 > 133`, third `True = 92 < 99 and 133 > 121`, fourth `True = 99 < 103 and 121 > 118`, fifth `False = 103 < 126 and 118 > 133`, sixth `False = 126 < 131 and 133 > 672`. That's what my code does and what your description suggests. If that's wrong, please tell for every row how the values should be calculated. Especially since you build differences from a 7-row-array between neighboring rows and still have 7 results instead of 6.

Comment: You are in fact correct. My apologies, i made a mistake in the last row. The value should be 67 not 672. I corrected that now. And the last (7nth row) is always false because there is not another row to compare it with.

Comment: One more thing. Can i test the same proposition using `assert`? It appears that with `assert` in Numpy you can only test certain things.

Comment: The assert functions in [`numpy.testing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.testing.html) are intended for testing. So in a test suite, you could say `numpy.testing.assert_equal(result, np.array([False,False, True, True, False, True, False]))` which would raise an error if not all elements are equal.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful. I would like to have an `if` statement to take action is `assert` fails. Should i do this using a combination of `try` and `exception`? Or is there a better way?

Comment: That's not the usecase for testing functions. That's a simple conditional: `if result == expectation:` _do something_ `else` _do something else_.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165973/discussion-between-user177324-and-ascripter).